# How can I prove that this function is uniformly continuous?

Tags: proof-writing, uniform-continuity

How to show that $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ is uniformly continuous?

Thank you. Also, how do I become good at writing these proofs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that it is differentiable, and has bounded derivative. Then use Lagrange's mean value theorem.

Comment: @user93765 Lagrange's mean value theorem is basic calculus. Maybe you're not used to that name? It says that if $f$ is a function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ with continuous derivative on $(a,b)$ we can find $\xi\in (a,b)$ such that $$f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(\xi)$$